# get from clicked row input values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

my table looks something like that:

```
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="edit-mode max" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="edit-mode min" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="edit-mode width" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <button name="Klickmich" type="button" value="Überraschung">Foo</Button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="max edit-mode" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="min edit-mode" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="edit-mode width" value="6" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <button name="Klickmich" type="button" value="Überraschung">Foo</Button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="edit-mode max" value="7" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="edit-mode min" value="8" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="edit-mode width" value="9" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <button name="Klickmich" type="button" value="Überraschung">Foo</Button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the user clicks on the row I want to save / fetch the values of the input values from the clicked row.

I did that with:

```
   $("button").click(function () {

    var min = jQuery("input#min").val();
    var max = jQuery("input#max").val();
    var width = jQuery("input#width").val();

    console.log(currentClass);
    console.log(min);
    console.log(max);
    console.log(width);
});
```

With this code I only get the values of the first row. I should revice the values from the clicked row. For example if the user clicks on the third row the values should be 7,8,9.

Also I'm  wondering why I get with $(this).parents('tr') the button context instead of the tr context in jquery.

Does someone have a good workaround for this? Code also here http://jsfiddle.net/zW5KC/1/

Comment: Id should be unique..!

Comment: You want results on clicking the row or the button at the end of the row?

Comment: one possible soultion : http://jsfiddle.net/zW5KC/2/

Comment: Sry, I adjusted my code and moved the ids to classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so firstly your IDs should be unique, so I've changed them to classes.

Secondly, when you try `var min = jQuery("input#min").val();` its finding an input with the id of min, however its just finding the first one on the page, it doesn't know which one you want.

So I've updated the code to use `this` which in this case references the actual button element you've clicked. From there we find the closest parent which is a `tr` and then from there find a child who has the correct class. Code;

```
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="max" class="edit-mode" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="min" class="edit-mode" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="width" class="edit-mode" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <button name="Klickmich" type="button" value="Überraschung">Foo</Button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="max" class="edit-mode" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="min" class="edit-mode" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="width" class="edit-mode" value="6" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <button name="Klickmich" type="button" value="Überraschung">Foo</Button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="max" class="edit-mode" value="7" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="min" class="edit-mode" value="8" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span class="display-mode" />
        <input class="width" class="edit-mode" value="9" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <button name="Klickmich" type="button" value="Überraschung">Foo</Button>
    </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("button").click(function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var min = $row.find('.min').val();
        var max = $row.find('.max').val();
        var width = $row.find('.width').val();

        console.log(currentClass);
        console.log(min);
        console.log(max);
        console.log(width);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to add at least a small description of your solution instead of lumping down a block of code

Comment: Yep sorry pre-emptively hit save.

Answer (score 1):

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find parent tr and then use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the specific element inside that tr like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var min = jQuery(this).closest("tr").find("#min").val();
    var max = jQuery(this).closest("tr").find("#max").val();
    var width = jQuery(this).closest("tr").find("#width").val();


    console.log(min);
    console.log(max);
    console.log(width);
});
```

Comment: Also you should cache your jQuery objects.

Comment: OP has been told in comments about not doing that way so OP will consider it

Comment: Thanks for bringing me into the right direction using closest.